# Error while CMS Import by content porter in SDL Web 8.5 with DXA 1.8

Tags: dxa, web8.5, content-porter, dxa-1.8

We have a fresh SDL Web 8.5 CMS installed under distributed architecture and we are trying to import DXA 1.8, while importing we are getting below error.

I tired both PowerShell and Content Porter 8.5. In PowerShell it abort the import due to execution policy. I tried doing publication import  one by one using CP `000 Empty` and `100 Master` got committed successfully but it throw this error when importing `110 DXA site type`

we have CD and CMS on different  machine, I hope that is not causing this issue.

Running PowerShell in admin mode. DB connectivity is checked.

```
2017/12/28 09:14:04 <1700> [Information] Building list of items to import and determining required import actions.
2017/12/28 09:14:04 <1700> [Information] Unzipping and initializing package for import.
2017/12/28 09:14:07 <1700> [Information] Discovery of potential problems started at 12/28/2017 9:14:07 AM.
2017/12/28 09:14:07 <1700> [Information] Import of system administration items started at 12/28/2017 9:14:07 AM.
2017/12/28 09:14:07 <1700> [Information] Import items into publication '000 Empty' started at 12/28/2017 9:14:07 AM.
2017/12/28 09:14:07 <1700> [Information] Import items into publication '100 Master' started at 12/28/2017 9:14:07 AM.
2017/12/28 09:14:09 <1700> [Error] System.InvalidOperationException: The ResolveEntitySet function must return a non-null Uri for the EntitySet 'CdTopologyTypes', otherwise you must set the BaseUri property.
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.UriResolver.GetEntitySetUri(String entitySetName)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.UriWriter.VisitQueryableResourceExpression(QueryableResourceExpression rse)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.UriWriter.Translate(DataServiceContext context, Boolean addTrailingParens, Expression e, Uri& uri, Version& version)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryProvider.Translate(Expression e)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.BusinessProcessType.OnSaved(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportAction.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<SaveItem>b__0(Boolean isRetry)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Process.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<InvokeInErrorHandler>b__0(Boolean isRetry)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.AbortErrorHandler.Invoke[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message, Boolean retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical, UserReply additionalUserReplyOptions)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Process.InvokeInErrorHandler[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message, Boolean retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportAction.SaveItem(IdentifiableObject item, IdentifiableObjectData deltaObject)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.CreateImportAction.Perform(IdentifiableObjectData itemData)
```

Answer (score 3):

Run ttm-prepare.ps1 which comes in your DXA package and it will preconfigure the Topology Manager for the DXA Site Type and Business Process Types.Also Please check Topology Manager is installed properly in IIS  and its CMDLET commands [click here](http://www.dominic.cronin.nl/weblog/finding-your-way-around-the-sdl-web-8-cmdlets) are available.

Answer (score 2):

Before you can import DXA you need a `fully operational` content delivery environment, as described [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v7&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-DD402008-D5C5-4DCA-A74F-893272D2B659&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-92CCBE97-76B6-4513-9D43-6D3DEAE31C7F.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-DD402008-D5C5-4DCA-A74F-893272D2B659)

This means you first need to setup the CD and Topology. The import is failing as it cannot find any `CdTopologyTypes`. If I recall correctly, you can use the `quickinstall' PowerShell script to setup a basic Topology.

A quick summary of doing this manually is available [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-3BD6ED93-41B7-4357-92DB-8AEA8DEFB0A1#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-52727C62-2976-476F-8F83-6A980DC585E7.xml&docid=GUID-52727C62-2976-476F-8F83-6A980DC585E7&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-52727C62-2976-476F-8F83-6A980DC585E7)